# Merge two files according hours

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, merge

I want two merge two files according an hour column.

File1 :

```
4:04:12 text1
12:56:32 text2
23:12:12 text3
```

File2 :

```
5:05:12 text4
18:12:19 text5
```

Output wanted :

```
4:04:12 text1
5:05:12 text4
12:56:32 text2
18:12:19 text5
23:12:12 text3
```

Comment: Don't expect the full code here. Please post some work that you already have made ;)

Comment: @tsippert the solution has just two words `sort -n` ... I bet he has made the longer one `sort`. :)

Comment: @Kent I didn't know that bash can be so powerfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the program `sort(1)`, like this:

```
sort -n File1 File2
```

Comment: i think accepted answer should be up voted. obviously you accepted the answer because it helped you @user2409399

Answer (score 0):

You can use command `sort -n` to achieve that

```
sort -n File1 File2
```

[`sort` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort):

> sort - sort lines of text files
>
> -n, --numeric-sort
> compare according to string numerical value